# Passing a value to an api to return all values

Tags: api, query-string

I have an API that has a query parameter called `type` (e.g `type=basketball`) which could return all values whose type is basketball. The only way I know through which I can get all types is to remove the `type` all together. I was wondering if it's possible to add a value for type which would return all the types instead of removing it from my api, something like `type=all`?

Comment: What is this API? OData standards compliant APIs have a standard syntax for such a query, but for almost everything else it would be highly dependant on the designer of the API to provide such functionality.

Comment: it's a custom API I get from backend. something like "www.source.com/sport?type=basketball". Well the idea is that I have a button which should return all sporting events regardless of their type. So I was wondering if there is a way to do it like that!

Comment: If you are the author of the API, then absolutely, you can do what you want, if you need help though your should try it first, paste your attempt into this post for further assistance.  You might also try `type=*`, but as you have already found, omitting the type filter altogether is a simple enough option